# Where is instance_eval defined in Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, documentation, instance-eval

Forgive my ignorance, but I must be missing something here. I can find the documentation for [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000005) for ruby 1.8.7 in the `Object` class, but I just cannot find it anywhere for [1.9.2](http://ruby-doc.org/core/). I know the functionality is still supported since I'm using it. Is there some secret parent class that it has been moved to?

Answer (score 5):

If you do `Object.superclass` you will see that that is `BasicObject` which itself has no superclass. Using `BasicObject.public_methods` reveals that `instance_eval` is defined there.

There [does not seem to be any documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/BasicObject.html) for the methods on `BasicObject`.

Comment: Ahh I see. Is there any particular reason why the documentation doesn't exist? Are they trying to discourage the usage of `instance_eval`? I also noticed that `method_missing` is not documented anywhere?
Also, the actual documentation for BasicObject is here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/BasicObject.html.

Comment: I spotted that link too, but the docs under /core-1.9 are for 1.9 whereas the docs under /core are for the latest (currently 1.9.2). It seems like the definition of `BasicObject` has moved from [object.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_0_0/object.c) to [class.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_2/class.c) in the move from 1.9 to 1.9.2 so that might account for the small amount of documentation you can see in core-1.9.